# Connect sql 2008 R2 with Java in eclipse

Tags: java, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to connect the Sql Server 2008 R2 with java using JDBC.I have downloaded the jdbc jar files and i added in the eclipse.When i try to connect to sql 2008 R2 it says the following error.I am using the default port 1433. whether i have to change setting on the sql side.

This is my code.

```
package SocketClient;

import java.sql.*;
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.*;

 public class SocketClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

  // Declare the JDBC objects.
  Connection con = null;
  CallableStatement cstmt = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;

  try {
     // Establish the connection. 
     SQLServerDataSource ds = new SQLServerDataSource();
     ds.setUser("sa");
     ds.setPassword("password123");
     ds.setServerName("ENMEDIA-EA6278E\\ENMEDIA");
     ds.setPortNumber(1433); 
     ds.setDatabaseName("DishTV_Voting");
     con = ds.getConnection();

     // Execute a stored procedure that returns some data.
     cstmt = con.prepareCall("{call dbo.uspGetEmployeeManagers(?)}");
     cstmt.setInt(1, 50);
     rs = cstmt.executeQuery();

     // Iterate through the data in the result set and display it.
     while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println("EMPLOYEE: " + rs.getString("LastName") + 
           ", " + rs.getString("FirstName"));
        System.out.println("MANAGER: " + rs.getString("ManagerLastName") + 
           ", " + rs.getString("ManagerFirstName"));
        System.out.println();
     }
  }

  // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
  catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
  finally {
     if (rs != null) try { rs.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
     if (cstmt != null) try { cstmt.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
     if (con != null) try { con.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
     System.exit(1);
  }
 }
}
```

the error which i am getting while connecting to sql is

**com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host      ENMEDIA-EA6278E, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".
    at            com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:170)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1049)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:833)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:716)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource.getConnectionInternal(SQLServerDataSource.java:577)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource.getConnection(SQLServerDataSource.java:57)
    at SocketClient.SocketClient.main(SocketClient.java:23)**

Can anyboby point me where i went wrong.Thanks in advance.Any tutorial for connecting sql with java along with installation of

Comment: That is, I hope, not the real password, is it?

Comment: And a production database?! Wait, you work for Sony, do you? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if SQL Server is configured (via Surface Area Configuration) to accept *remote* TCP/IP connections.

Answer (score 0):

> Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.

The hints in your stacktrace are pointing to a blocked connection. Would be worthwile to check if you can get a connection through other means (ping, database client, telnet, ..). There is an Eclipse plugin to explore databases too; if you can get the connection working there ..

Cheers,
Wim